# In CUDA kernel, how can I process one column in one thread for image values

Tags: image, cuda, processing

My image is grayscale. I want to process average of column in one thread using `float*` type. And I want to add my output pixel's value with average value. When I launch it I can see just one row. I'm unable to understand what is happening.

```
__global__ void processing(float* in, float* out, int COL, int ROW)
{
    int row=10;
    int col=10;
    __shared__ float u_shared[10];
    int idx=threadx.x
    if (idx>=N){return;}

    float mean = 0;
    if ( idx < COL) 
    {    
        for (int jdx=0; jdx < ROW; ++jdx)
        {
            mean += in[idx*ROW+jdx];
        }
        u_shared[idx] = mean/ROW;

        for (int jdxx=0; jdxx < ROW; ++jdxx)
        {
            out[idx*ROW+jdxx] =  in[idx*ROW+jdxx]+mean;
        }
    }     
}

kernel<<<1,10>>> // one thread for one column
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (Coded in browser, not tested):

```
__global__ void processing(float* in, float* out, int COL, int ROW)
{
        int idx=threadx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        float mean = 0;
        if ( idx < COL) 
        {    
          for (int jdx=0; jdx < ROW; ++jdx)
          {
              mean += in[jdx*COL+idx];
          }
          mean /= ROW;
          for (int jdx=0; jdx < ROW; ++jdx)
          {
              out[jdx*COL+idx] =  mean + in[jdx*COL+idx];
          }
        }     
}
```

If your image has 1000 rows,  5000 columns, you would launch it like this:

```
#define NROW 1000
#define NCOL 5000
#define nTPB 256
processing<<<(NCOL+nTPB-1)/nTPB, nTPB>>>(in_data, out_data, NCOL, NROW);
```

This assumes ordinary, non-pitched allocations for input and output.

Comment: thanks you very much Robert. I tested but why just one row is seeming. I can't understand. My example code for just 10x10 image.